# arraylist y/n to enter values in java

Tags: java, arraylist

i need to create an array list with 3 fields (each a string) this code isnt working and need assistance fixing it. the task seems pretty straight forward but i am unable to figure out whats wrong. i am running netbeans

here is what i have so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class scientist1
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    Scanner kbd1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Document> someStuff = new ArrayList<Document>();
    char quit = 'Y';
    String scientist, field, greatIdea;

        while (quit == 'Y')
        {
            System.out.print("\n Scientists name: ");
            scientist = scan.next();
            System.out.print(" scientists field: ");
            field = scan.next();
            System.out.print(" Scientists great Ideas: ");
            greatIdea = scan.nextInt();
            someStuff.add (new Document(field, scientist, greatIdea));
            System.out.print(" Enter Another Scientist? (Y/N)");
            String word = scan.next();
            word = word.toUpperCase();
            quit= word.charAt(0);
        }
        for(Document stuff : someStuff)
        System.out.println(stuff);
}
}



public class Document
{
public static String scientist, field;
private int greatIdea;
public Document (String Last, String First,String Idea)
{
    scientist = First;
    field = Last;
    greatIdea = Idea;
}
public String toString ()
{
    return "\n\n Name: " + field + ", " + scientist + "\n Document Code: " + greatIdea + "\n";
}
public boolean equals (Object other)
{
    return (field.equals(((Document)other).getLast())&&
    scientist.equals(((Document)other).getFirst()));
}
public int compareTo (Object other)
{
    int result;
    String otherFirst = ((Document)other).getFirst();
    String otherLast = ((Document)other).getLast();
    if (field.equals(otherLast))
        result = scientist.compareTo(otherFirst);
    else
        result = field.compareTo(otherLast);
    return result;
}
public String getFirst ()
{
    return scientist;
}
public String getLast ()
{
    return field;
}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have `static` here I suppose -> `public static String scientist, field;`

Comment: Just quickly does it **HAVE** to be a bubble sort?

Comment: no it doesnt have to be a bubble sort. i thought it was easiest.

Comment: @Domisaur Okay. Can I clarify you want to extract the sort the documents by the name of the scientist?

Comment: yep i wanted to extract data tied to the name of the scientist by searching the scientiests name in the program. my main issue is just getting the arraylist with 3 parts right now though @Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay to show you how to do it and to give you a chance to solve the problems with your code I made an example. Like nerdlyist I nested the a class inside the main class for simplicity. I also used the inbuilt sort function, suggested by hagmic, from the comparator class. This means it saves time and effort because you don't have to write your own comparator.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Test {
    private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    private List<LayoutOfScientist> scientistsNames = new ArrayList<LayoutOfScientist>();
    private String name, field, idea;
    private boolean continueLoop = true;
    private int countTo3 = 0;

    private void run() {
        while(countTo3<3&&continueLoop) {
            if(countTo3>0) {
                System.out.println("Would you like to add another scientist? (Y/N)");
            }

            if(countTo3 == 0 || scan.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                System.out.println("Please enter the scientist's name:");
                name = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter the scientist's field:");
                field = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter the scientist's idea:");
                idea = scan.nextLine();
                scientistsNames.add(new LayoutOfScientist(name, field, idea));
            } else {
                continueLoop = false;
            }
            countTo3++;
        }

        scientistsNames.sort(Comparator.comparing(LayoutOfScientist::getScientistName));
        for(LayoutOfScientist lOS : scientistsNames) {
            System.out.println(lOS.getScientistName() + ", " + lOS.getScientistField() + ", " + lOS.getScientistIdea());
        }
    }

    private class LayoutOfScientist {
        private String scientistName, scientistField, scientistIdea;

        private LayoutOfScientist(String scientistName, String scientistField, String scientistIdea) {
            this.scientistName = scientistName;
            this.scientistField = scientistField;
            this.scientistIdea = scientistIdea;
        }

        public String getScientistName() {
            return scientistName;
        }

        public String getScientistField() {
            return scientistField;
        }

        public String getScientistIdea() {
            return scientistIdea;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().run();
    }
}
```

Example input

```
Dan
Space
2
Y
Tom
Earth
3
Y
Bob
Space
6
```

Output

```
Bob, Space, 6
Dan, Space, 2
Tom, Earth, 3
```

Comment: i dont mean to sound so lost but i am that lost haha

Comment: i never intended the code for the third one to be an int either, but thanks.

Comment: @Domisaur No problem. If this helped solve your problem could you click the tick next to the answer just to let others know your problem has been solved? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8 you can do this by using [List.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) as follows:

```
someStuff.sort(Comparator.comparing(Document::getScientist));
```

If you are using less than Java 8 you will need to do this by implementing the [Comparator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface and then use [Collections.sort](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to sort your objects.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this would be declaring an arraylist of String arrays.
So something like:

```
ArrayList<String[]> someStuff = new ArrayList<String[]>;
```

One issue with this method is that every time you append a new element onto someStuff you will need to initialize that indivual String array:
For example:

```
someStuff.add(new String[] {"Scientist", "Field", "Idea"});
```

Or:

```
someStuff.add(new String[3]);
```

At this point I would recommend using either of 2 String functions:

```
compareTo(String str)
```

Or:

```
compareToIgnoreCase(String str)
```

Within a sort function which organizes the ArrayList by Scientist names.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is getting your Docs into the list not the sorting. In order to do that you should resolve the 8 errors that were being spit out. The below code is cleaned up with some notes. Major change is that I made Document a nested class for my ease of compiling (you can take it back out and import it).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class scientist1 {
    static class Document  {
        private String scientist, field, greatIdea; //Stay consistent with private and removed static.

        public Document  (String last, String first, String idea)
        {
            scientist = first;
            field = last;
            greatIdea = idea;
        }
        public String toString ()
        {
            return "\n\n Name: " + field + ", " + scientist + "\n Document  Code: " + greatIdea + "\n";
        }
        public boolean equals (Object other)
        {
            return (field.equals(((Document )other).getLast())&&
            scientist.equals(((Document )other).getFirst()));
        }
        public int compareTo (Object other)
        {
            int result;
            String otherFirst = ((Document )other).getFirst();
            String otherLast = ((Document )other).getLast();
            if (field.equals(otherLast))
                result = scientist.compareTo(otherFirst);
            else
                result = field.compareTo(otherLast);
            return result;
        }
        public String getFirst ()
        {
            return scientist;
        }
        public String getLast ()
        {
            return field;
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Document > someStuff = new ArrayList<Document >();
        char quit = 'Y';
        String scientist, field, greatIdea;

        while (quit == 'Y')
        {
            System.out.print("\n Scientists name: ");
            scientist = scan.next();
            System.out.print(" scientists field: ");
            field = scan.next();
            System.out.print(" Scientists great Ideas: ");
            greatIdea = scan.next();
            someStuff.add(new Document (field, scientist, greatIdea));
            System.out.print(" Enter Another Scientist? (Y/N)");
            String word = scan.next();
            word = word.toUpperCase();
            quit= word.charAt(0);
        }
        for(Document  stuff : someStuff){
            System.out.println(stuff);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i can enter the inital info but i cant get the option to loop it

Comment: Have you made changes? I re-ran this an the loop and output work fine.

Comment: im using netbeans if that makes the difference. but after i enter the information i just get an error. also i never intended for it the great ideas to be an int it was also supposed to be a string

Comment: @Domisaur are you doing things other then string for greatIdeas when you run this? That will cause errors then. The code was edited to allow for string.

Answer (score 0):

**Just 3 minor mistakes..**

1. Instance of `Scanner` is named `kbd1` but used as `scan`

   Scanner kbd1 = new Scanner(System.in);

//using like  scientist = scan.next();

//use as

```
Scanner kbd1 = new Scanner(System.in);
scientist = kbd1.next();
```

2. String greatIdea;//string variable
   //inputting as int

   greatIdea = kbd1.nextInt();//wrong
3. In the Document class

private int greatIdea;//must be String

Thats all, you are good to go.

PS: sorry for improper format

Comment: ok I didn't check your code thoroughly, so there may be logical errors (during sorting or so)....check them out